# Parquet generated using Azure data factory - not able to create table in Hive

Tags: azure, hive, azure-data-factory, parquet

Parquet file is generated from Azure Data Factory (copy activity - copying from Azure SQL to Parquet in data lake). When I am trying it read same parquet from Hive it is giving error as org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 0 in block.

If you generating parquet using Spark then you can set Spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat=true but how to handle same thing in Azure Data Factory.

Issue is coming for Decimal conversions

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused because of different parquet conventions used in Hive and Spark.

I assume Hive guesses the decimal as fixed-bytes but Spark actually writes out them as INT32 for 1<= precision <=9 and INT 64 for 10 <= precision <=18.

Errors like these caused with a schema that had **DECIMAL** field. Try using **DOUBLE** instead of **DECIMAL**.